# How to make sure GPUAcceleration for Silverlight is really on?

Tags: silverlight, performance, gpu, acceleration

I can have a lot of controls in my layoutroot (a canvas). And as the tree gets bigger, performance naturally fades and eventually the application becomes unresponsive to most actions.. To give my creep a little push, I am trying to use the [GPUAcceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) but I havenT seen any enhancement in the performance and more importantly I couldnT find a way to make sure if it is even trying.

Say I have this set on the Aspx host page of an SL app:

```
<asp:Silverlight ID="O2PSilverlightXaml" runat="server" Source="O2PSilverlight.xap"
EnableFrameRateCounter="true" MinimumVersion="3.0.40307.0" Width="100%" Height="100%"
EnableGPUAcceleration="true" />
```

How do i make sure if it worked? How do I know that my graphics card is supported or that it wasnT ignored due to the security settings of the browser ...etc?

This is for Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) you are linking to:

> During profiling and performance tuning phases of application
>   development, you can set EnableCacheVisualization (Silverlight Plug-in
>   Object) to true to produce an overlay visualization of the areas in
>   your UI that are being hardware accelerated.

[This will give you a visual clue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833081%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309563(v=VS.95).aspx) it says : "Notice that not everything can be hardware accelerated. " so i thought, maybe i was not using anything that could be cached.. But having read it again, as far as I understood, there are only a few exceptions (DropShadowEffect, WriteableBitmap  and OpacityMask)...
If this is the case, I should see the overlays which I still donT :).. (in IE9)

Comment: Are you using the CacheMode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cachemode(v=VS.95).aspx to give hints for caching?

Comment: Yes. But I set it for the main control which is pretty much the entire thing (since I havenT read anything on the potential drawbacks to do so)

Comment: That is bad practice. You should only cache controls that do not change or are changed by translation, scaling, rotation etc. GPU caching is just caching a bitmap of a control. Changes to the control other than changes that can be performed by the gpu invalidate the cached bitmap.